# How to extend a type with an onChange event

Tags: c#, winforms

Specifically I want to add an onChange event to the string class, how can I do that?

I have a dictionary of strings as a member of one of my classes.  One or more of these strings might have functions that need to be called when they change.  This function is defined by the code using the class.

If it's possible, the simplest way to do this seems to be to add an event handler to string or to make a new class that inherits from string and have my dictionary hold them.  How would I do this?

update:

My dictionary is currently of strings, but I can change it to int or dynamic without too much fuss.

Comment: Took my downvote back on reading "my finger slipped an I hit enter on acciden" :D

Comment: Encapsulate it in a class, add code to a setter/update method and implement an event/INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: The strings aren't changing, the value for that key is.

Comment: Strings don't change.  A dictionary's contents can change, but a string does not.

Comment: Strings are immutable - all their modification properties create a new string instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are sealed.  You can not inherit from them.  In any case, they are immutable, and can never be changed.  The closest thing you can do is using `INotifyPropertyChanged` to subscribe to property changes in an object.  In this example, I create a listener that gets updated when one of the property values in `Foo` changes.

```
void Main() {
    var f = new Foo();
    f.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => 
        Console.WriteLine ("Changed: {0}", e.PropertyName);

    f.Name = "asdf";
    f.Size = 123;
}

class Foo
    : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _Name;
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
            this._Name = value;
        }
    }

    private int _Size;
    public int Size {
        get {
            return this._Size;
        }
        set {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Size"));
            }
            this._Size = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Changed: Name
Changed: Size
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no point adding such an event to a string, because strings are immutable.  You cannot change their contents, only create new strings with the content you want.

Now, you *can* modify a string *variable* by changing what string value it points to.  For instance, in this code:

```
string s = "Hello";
s = s + " there";
```

a new string is made by concatenating the two strings "Hello" and " there".  Then the variable `s` is updated to point to the new string.  If the `string` class had a `Changed` event, and you listened for changes on `s`, like this:

```
string s = "Hello";
s.Changed += ((sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("changed!"));
s = s + " there";
```

the event would never fire and the message would never be seen.  That's because, in the assignment `s = s + " there"`, the string with which you registered an event handler is discarded.  You registered for changes on the string "Hello", which was replaced by the new string "Hello there".

You have a similar situation with your Dictionaries.  Consider the following code, again using the fictitious `Changed` event:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["foo"] = "bar";
dict["foo"].Changed += ((sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("changed!"));
dict["foo"] = "the replacement string";
```

Here, again, the `Changed` event will never fire and the message will never show, because you are never changing the value of the string "bar".  Rather, you are replacing the string "bar" with another string, "the replacement string".  The string "bar" is discarded.

What you *can* do, as others have suggested, is define a new class where access to the data structure must go through gatekeeper methods of your own where you identify cases that modify the internal data structure and fire a `Changed` event accordingly.

Comment: Though your more than likely correct, more of a comment than an answer since it is still unclear what OP is asking.

Comment: An option would be to wrap in an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class. This does not help the OP get to that conclusion.

Comment: @Bas That would be doing none of the things the question mentions.  If the OP actually describes a problem that *can* be solved, then he can get answers that solve it.  If he only asks how to do something that's both impossible and pointless, he'll get that as an answer.

Comment: @Servy Technically/literally you are absolutely correct, however the OP doesn't realize strings are sealed immutable in .NET (which is not something that is super obvious or the case in every programming language/platform). This should not prevent him from getting completely blocked.

Comment: @Bas Such is the consequences of failing to provide adequate information in the question.  Hopefully he'll learn enough from the answer to his question to ask a new question that allows him to more effectively describe his problem in a way that answers can help him solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to implement an "observable dictionary".

What you might want to consider is implementing an [IDictionary TKey, TVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (you could just have a generic Dictionary as a backing store) and have [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h(v=vs.110).aspx) 's setter fire an event?